# shell scripting string replace using shell variables

Tags: bash, shell, unix

This is my very basic script:

```
  temp=hello 
  while read line;
  do
     echo ${line}
  done
```

However, ${line} will itself consist of "value of temp = ${temp}"

I want my script to echo "value of temp is hello".  I've tried doing many things, even

```
echo `echo ${line}`
```

but each time it always just prints "value of temp is ${temp}"

I hope this question is clear. THanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
temp=hello 
while read line; do
    echo "Value of temp = `eval echo ${line}`"
done
```

Then in the console just type:

```
${temp}
```

Comment: Thanks mate. That seems to work, what I did was replace the middle line with simply: eval echo "${line}"... Thank! (I'd upvote but don't have the karma apparently)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have solutions with `eval`, but using eval is mauvais ton, actually.

```
$> cat 7627845.sh 
#!/bin/bash

temp=hello 
cat file_with_values.log | while read line;
do
    eval echo "${line}"
done


$> cat file_with_values.log 
value of temp = ${temp}

$> ./7627845.sh 
value of temp = hello
```

Comment: useless use of `cat`: `while read line; do eval echo "$line"; done < file_with_values.log`

Comment: Frankly speaking there is no huge difference between those methods.

Comment: depends what you're doing in the while body. If you `cat file | while ...` then the while command runs in a subshell, and any variables you set in the while body disappear when the subshell ends. So, potentially, there could be a huge difference. Obviously, that's not the case here, but this is a teaching site, so it's better to teach good principles.